# bokeh event to announce a button click on a plot RedoTool

Tags: python, bokeh

Looking to run a callback in `bokeh` when there is a button click on a plot `RedoTool`.  The following are available to import from `bokeh.events` and not clear if there is support for a button click on the `RedoTool` (and also the `UndoTool`).

````
    DocumentEvent           MouseWheel              RotateEnd
    DocumentReady           Pan                     RotateStart
    DoubleTap               PanEnd                  SelectionGeometry
    Event                   PanStart                Tap
    LODEnd                  Pinch                   _CONCRETE_EVENT_CLASSES
    LODStart                PinchEnd                __all__
    log                     PinchStart              __doc__
    logging                 PlotEvent               __file__
    MenuItemClick           PointEvent              __name__
    ModelEvent              Press                   __package__
    MouseEnter              PressUp
    MouseLeave              Reset```
````

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is nothing for this in `bokeh.events`, so you would need a workaround. In the past I was using the "Bokeh template" solution together with JQuery for this (still works for v2.1.1) You can access all Bokeh models by referring to its name attribute.

```
import os
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.util.browser import view

template = """
{% block postamble %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.querySelectorAll('.bk-tool-icon-redo[title="Redo"]')
                .forEach(d => d.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    var p = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('MyPlot')
                    var l = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('MyLine')
                    console.log(l.data_source.data)
                    l.data_source.data["y"] = [3,2,1]
                    l.data_source.change.emit()
                    
                    alert('Redo button clicked for ' + p.title.text);
                  }));
                  
            document.querySelectorAll('.bk-tool-icon-undo[title="Undo"]')
                .forEach(d => d.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    var p = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('MyPlot')
                    alert('Undo button clicked for ' + p.title.text);
                  }))
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %} """

p = figure(tools='pan, redo, undo, reset, save', title="Line Plot", name="MyPlot")
p.line([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], name="MyLine")
save(p, template=template)
view(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.basename(__file__)).replace('.py', ".html"))
```

Comment: Have created a Feature Request to add the event handlers at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/11295

Comment: Then now you must have lots of patience. My experience is that it won't happend soon :)

Comment: In my experience the update can be fast especially if helping with the contribution.  In this case looks like there will be a `RangesUpdate` event in `bokeh 2.4`.  Please see the response to the Feature Request (it was closed) and the following PR: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/11125